# Connecting to mysql from php fails silently

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a server running on linux from a php file using the following file:

```
<?php
    $db_host = "127.0.0.1";
    $db_user = "userk";
    $db_pss = "pass";

    $tag = $_POST['tag'];
    echo $tag . " Trying to connect with credentials: "
         . $db_host."\n". $db_user . " " .$db_pss;

    $link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user,$db_pss);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    mysql_close($link);
?>
```

the output page is:

> register Trying to connect with credentials: 127.0.0.1 userk pass

I've checked previous questions looking for useful information. But it still doesn't work.

I'm able to connect to mysql with this user from terminal using putty. I don't know why I don't receive any messages after the connection attempt. Should I check the firewall configuration on the server, how can I check that?

Thanks!

Comment: try $db_host = "localhost";

Comment: does it work if you replace 127.0.0.1 with "localhost"? also is there meant to be a "k" on the end of user?

Comment: yes the user is "userk".

Comment: And what is the actual error that `mysql_error()` outputs?

Comment: There are no errors. The `mysql_error()` does not return an output. I've checked the log files in /var/log/mysql.log and mysql.error but they are empty.

Answer (score 1):

**As we know mysql_* is depreciated now,  so better use it using MYSQLI_*:**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_NOTICE | E_STRICT );
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "userk";
$db_pss = "pass";
$database="abc";

$tag = $_POST['tag'];
echo $tag . " Trying to connect with credentials: " . $db_host."\n". $db_user . " " .$db_pss" " .$database;

$link = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user,$db_pss,$database);
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($link));
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

It can be a case that your errors are suppressed. So its not showing an error. try it out. It will give the error now. That will help figuring out real problem.:)

Comment: I've changed the database name with the one I'm using and same result... "register Trying to connect with credentials: localhost userk pss gamble"

Comment: Same output as before. Is it possible that the errors have been suppressed in the mysql configuration file?

Comment: In the php.ini there was the line display_errors = Off! I've changed it to On. Finally it displays messages! But the error is "Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /var/www/gepp/Gamble/PHP/index1.php on line 18" which is not encouraging...

Comment: uncomment lines `extension=php_mysql.dll` and `extension=php_mysqli.dll` in your php.ini and Restart all services of your web server. and do check phpinfo() for mysql_connect

Comment: There are no lines like that. The server uses linux so I've added the line extension=mysql.so. I wasn't sure about the path so I inserted the path returned by the `locate mysql.so` command from the terminal. Anyway it does not work. I get the same error and the phpinfo() command does not show any mysql line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "userk";
$db_pss = "pass";

$tag = $_POST['tag'];
echo $tag . " Trying to connect with credentials: " . $db_host."\n". $db_user . " " .$db_pss;

$link = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user,$db_pss);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

try this :)

Comment: Same result..."register Trying to connect with credentials: localhost userk pss"

Comment: i tried this on my local server and it worked ok check the username and password also take notice of Rahul answer :)

Comment: mysql user and password are correct, I'm able to connect from terminal using putty with `mysql -uuserk -p[password]`. I've tried with the root user but same problem. With the `die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());` line it is supposed to return something at least an error.